# DialogFragment isn't attached when I try to update it?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-service, android-mediaplayer

My attempt to simply/clearly explain a requirement to play music, show mp3 detail like time elapsed/remaining, and scrubbing with seek bar.

Activity hosts Fragment. Service has MediaPlayer.

Fragment *simultaneously* starts service and displays Dialog.

Dialog buttons control MediaPlayer. I can pause/play using av controls from the dialog.

NullPointerException occurs when I try to set dialog views with info. Seems the problem is that dialog doesn't attach quick enough for me to update with media player details and set seek bar progression.

I wasn't initially using a service but that approach didn't satisfy other requirements, like seamless audio on rotation and playing audio even if the dialog gets closed by the user.

[Project source available on GitHub.](https://github.com/es0329/Workshop)

[image: sketch diagram]

Update #1. Add stacktrace. Crash occurs at PreviewDialog.java:112. I commented this line in the linked repo with a note to uncomment in order to observe NPE.

```
0-07 14:35:09.475 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
10-07 14:35:09.495 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
10-07 14:35:09.500 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.es0329.workshop, PID: 12202
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.es0329.workshop.PreviewDialog.updateUi(PreviewDialog.java:112)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.es0329.workshop.PreviewDialog.onEvent(PreviewDialog.java:97)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.es0329.workshop.EventBus.publish(EventBus.java:40)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.es0329.workshop.MusicService$2.onPrepared(MusicService.java:50)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2548)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
10-07 14:35:09.502 12202-12202/com.es0329.workshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Update #2. Post code snippet. When the MediaPlayer is ready, it notifies the dialog. If the dialog receives a message of "READY" it calls the #updateUi below. From what I can tell, the service begins and the mediaplayer data is ready/available BEFORE my dialog (which contains that timeRemaining textView) is attached.

```
private void updateUi(MediaPlayer player) {
  int timeRemainingValue = player.getDuration();
  timeRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemainingValue)); // NPE! 
}
```

Comment: Could you please copy the stacktrace and put it in your question? The error and the description. It will show you in which line is the error.

Comment: @GeorgeRappel As requested, I updated post with log output.

Comment: You can see on the stacktrace that the problem is inside `updateUi` function. `PreviewDialog.java:112` File PreviewDialog, line 112. Also, the message says that you're trying to use setText on a null text view. So you're trying to find the wrong textview or the wrong way. If you can't find the error by yourself on that textview, put that part of the code here and i'll help you.

Comment: Right. I follow the log but how to remedy what sounds like a race condition is lost on me. Offending code posted.

Comment: I see you're using Butterknife. I don't know much about it, you can try to use the default declaration to see if it works, then you could find out if it's a  problem on your layout, binding or logic. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I tried setting the textView in the conventional way too but I get the same NPE at that line. No worries @GeorgeRappel, I appreciate you taking the time to check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch statement around the setting of the time remaining to handle to Null pointer exception.

General comment: I used created a new thread in my service which would update the UI information (i.e. duration text and SeekBar).